# how to correctly compile java files with javac?

Tags: java, ubuntu-14.04, javac

So I am trying to compile some java codes from the the terminal without eclipse.
I was following this tutorial 
https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-rmi-hello-world-example/
So I got the 3 java files downloaded and I compiled them with
`javac *.java`
no error and I got 3 .class file

but when I ran
`java ServerOperation`
 I got

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ServerOperation (wrong name: com/mkyong/rmiserver/ServerOperation)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:803)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:442)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:64)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:348)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:347)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:312)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
```

I think I did not compile the files correctly but I don't know how to do it. 
what command should I use to compile?

update:
Fixed after removing all the package declaration 
How do I mark this as resolved 
Special thanks to Tom for his useless comments

Comment: Why don't you read the tutorial you linked to. It tells you how to run it: java com.mkyong.rmiserver.ServerOperation

Comment: I know what the error message means but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: and clearly java com.mkyong.rmiserver.ServerOperation  is not going to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compilation was correct.

However, your main class is placed in a *package*.

This is because of the first line of `ServerOperation.java`:

```
package com.mkyong.rmiserver;
```

In order to run the program, you have to include the package while running main class. That means you have to navigate to the root of package/directory (in this case, just before `com` folder).

While there type:

```
$ java com.mkyong.rmiclient.ServerOperation
```